# How compose java and Postgres in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have this YAML file

```yaml
  version: '2'
services:
  app:
    image: 'docker-spring-boot-postgres:latest'
    ports:
      - "8085:8085"
    build:
      context: C:\Users\Grigor_Martirosyan\IdeaProjects\docker\src\main\docker\Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=admin
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update

  db:
    image: 'postgres:13.1-alpine'
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
```

the app says connection error

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

I tried to change connection details but still gives that error, it just changed, before it gave like TCP/IP error .but now that error.

Now it gives this error

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Comment: When you set `$SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL`, use the Compose service name `db` as the host name part of the URL.  In Docker `localhost` usually means "the current container", not another container or the containing host.  Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze so my localhost testdb can't be dockerized?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze do i need to instal postgre on docker?

Comment: The Compose file already has a PostgreSQL database, but its `localhost` is a different `localhost` from the application container's `localhost` or your host system's `localhost`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze I mean if your spring boot application has Postgres database deployed on AWS , then do need to compose it or not?

Comment: You don't need to start a second one via Compose in that case; but note that the RDS database _also_ won't be `localhost`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze thanks a lot